# How to push a value into an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I've got a problem to insert some values into an hash array, for a neat screen print.

#### File Input

```
#2.#2018 05 24 10:43:38:683#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9E50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER1#5##C47731E44D00000bae##0#Thread[HTTP
Worker [@1473726842],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain## Login
User: USER1 IP Address: 127.0.0.1 Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.#2018 05 24 11:05:04:011#+0200#Info#/Sy/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103EC9F50000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER4#6##A40B81404D03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP
Worker [@1264376989],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain## Login
User: USER4 IP Address: 127.0.0.1 Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.#2018 05 24 11:05:07:100#+0200#Info#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA0C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER3#7##9ACF7Ec0bae##0#Thread[HTTP
Worker [@124054179],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain## Logout
User: USER3 IP Address: 127.0.0.1 Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.#2018 05 24 11:07:21:314#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20E0000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#03c0bae##0#Thread[HTTP
Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain## Login
User: USER2 IP Address: 127.0.0.1 Authentication Stack: ticket
Authentication Stack Properties:

#2.#2018 05 02 10:48:05:700#+0200#Warn#/Sys/Sec/Authentication#
#BC-JAS-SEC#security#C0000A7103ECA20050000508C#3935150000000004#common.com/irj#com.common.services.security.authentication.logincontext.table#USER2#0##E0E##0#Thread[HTTP
Worker [@2033389552],5,Dedicated_Application_Thread]#Plain## Logout
User: USER2 IP Address: 127.0.0.1 Authentication Stack: ticket
```

#### Desired output

```
Date;Time;Type;User
2018/05/24;10:43:38:683;Login;USER1
2018/05/24;11:05:04:011;Login;USER4
2018/05/24;11:05:07:100;Logout;USER3
2018/05/24;11:07:21:314;Login;USER2
```

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature qw(say);

my $path = "mylog.txt";
open( FILE, $path ) or die $!;

my @array;
my $i = 0;

my %csv = ( l_d => 'Date', l_t => 'Time', l_msg => 'Type', l_usr => 'User', cr => '\n', );

while ( @array = <FILE> ) {

    foreach my $line ( @array ) {

        if ( $line =~ m/^#\d.\d.#\d{4}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}#\+\d+#\w+#\/\w+\/\w+\/Authentication/ ) {

            if ( $array[ $i + 2 ] =~ m/Login/ || $array[ $i + 2 ] =~ m/Logout/ && $array[ $i + 3 ] !~ m/NOUSER/ ) {

                my $l_d = substr( $line, 6, 10 );
                $l_d =~ s/\s/\//g;

                my $l_t   = substr( $line, 17, 12 );
                my $l_msg = substr( $array[ $i + 2 ], 0,  -1 );
                my $l_usr = substr( $array[ $i + 3 ], 6 );

                print "Date: $l_d\n";
                print "Time: $l_t\n";
                print "Type: $l_msg\n";
                print "User: $l_usr\n";

                # I would push these value into %csv('*')
                #push @{ %csv->{l_d}->[$l_d] }, $l_d;       # I would push into %csv('l_d') the $l_d value
                #push @{ %csv->{l_t}->[$l_t] }, $l_t;       # I would push into %csv('l_t') the $l_t value
                #push @{ %csv->{l_msg}->[$l_msg] }, $l_msg; # I would push into %csv('l_msg') the $l_t value
                #push @{ %csv->{l_usr}->[$l_usr] }, $ld_usr;# I would push into %csv('l_usr') the $l_t value
                # End of loop
            }
        }

        $i++;
    }
}

close( FILE );

print "Csv Example:\n\n";
print "$csv{'l_d'};$csv{'l_t'};$csv{'l_msg'};$csv{'l_usr'}\n";

#open my $filecsv, '>', 'outfile.csv' or die $!;
#$csv->print( $filecsv, \%csv );
```

I'm having trouble putting the original log file, because as soon as I insert it it is mishandled.

[Link is to `mylog.txt` file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gOhWYqW7VqeoMSJch6PX6LYn1OHpCbmM)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the expected output. You're not actually using the data structure you are creating. Also, you are mixing up some things. You have a `%csv` hash, but you are using a hash reference called `$csv` inside of the loop. Your code should not actually compile, but rather error out. And your regex pattern does not match your input. Please show us your real code. Just adding `use strict` at the top and not running it is not going to help.

Comment: I've add input file in the post :) thanks

Comment: Thanks for adding the input. You've still not run that code. It's getting more and more mixed up. If you were my trainee at this point I'd tell you to throw the code away and start over. It seems like you're just poking in the dark. Please try to run your code before posting it here. If it doesn't run, and you don't understand why, please [edit] and include the error messages you are getting. We really can't help otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some tricks that can make things much simpler.

- Change the input record separator so you read entire (multi-line) records at once. Do that with `$/`.
- Once you have the multi-line record, break it into lines. You know the position of the various things in the order of lines.
- Output the result as you process each line. You don't need a data structure for that.
- For more complicated things, look at [Text::CSV_XS](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV_XS) to handle the complexities of comma-separated values files.

---

```
$/ = "\n\n";  # record separator
while( <FILE> ) {
    chomp;
    my @lines = split /\n/;
    my ($y, $m, $d, $time ) =
        $lines[0] =~ /\A\#\d+\.\#(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+([^#]+)/;
    my $action = $lines[-2];
    my $user = (split /\s+/, $lines[-1])[-1];

    say join ';',
        "$y/$m/$d",
        $time,
        $action,
        $user
    }
```

---

But, now let's answer the titular question that may have brought people here. You want to store an array as a hash value. That's easy. An array reference (really, all references), are scalars. You can do the same thing you can do with scalars including using them as hash values:

```
my @array = ( ... );
my %hash;

$hash{'some_key'} = \@array;  # take a reference to a named array
```

You don't need a named array though. The `[ ]` creates an array reference directly:

```
$hash{'some_key'} = [ ... ];  # anonymous array constructor
```

Now you have this array reference value as your hash key and you want to do array-ish things with it. First you need to dereference it. Put the thing that returns the array reference inside `@{ }`:

```
@{ $hash{'some_key'} }
```

Use that wherever you'd use the named array:

```
push @{ $hash{'some_key'} }, 'new value';
pop @{ $hash{'some_key'} };
```

Perl v5.24 has the [postfix dereferencing feature](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/04/postfix-dereferencing-is-stable-is-v5-24/) that makes this a bit prettier:

```
$hash{'some_key'}->@*
```

Use that in place of the array:

```
push $hash{'some_key'}->@*, 'newer value';
pop $hash{'some_key'}->@*;
```

Comment: Technically, `->@*` has been available since 5.20, thought you'll need to add `use feature qw( postderef ); no warnings qw( experimental::postderef );` to use them before 5.24.